# About Kotlin Multiplatform AndroidNative who can help me. I searched kotlinlang, stackoverflow, google, but there was no specific way to use it

Tags: kotlin-native, android-native-library

I want to implement the library generated by Android calling AndroidNativeArm64 in the Kotlin Mulitplatform project. I've gone through almost all the documentation at kotlinlang.org and still don't know how to do it. Also searching on google and stackoverflow and github, no good reference. Is there an example of this? I tried a few things on my own, but it went wrong.

I did the following in the IntelliJ IDE:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqnJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYefX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpMXu.png)

Configure gradle according to the documentation to produce klib and so files:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXjlW.jpg)

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html#publish-your-library-to-the-local-maven-repository

The library has been published to the local Maven repository:

```
/Users/dxy/.m2/repository/me
└── dxy
├── mytestlib
│   ├── 1.0.0
│   │   ├── mytestlib-1.0.0-kotlin-tooling-metadata.json
│   │   ├── mytestlib-1.0.0-sources.jar
│   │   ├── mytestlib-1.0.0.jar
│   │   ├── mytestlib-1.0.0.module
│   │   └── mytestlib-1.0.0.pom
│   └── maven-metadata-local.xml
└── mytestlib-androidnativearm64
├── 1.0.0
│   ├── mytestlib-androidnativearm64-1.0.0-sources.jar
│   ├── mytestlib-androidnativearm64-1.0.0.klib
│   ├── mytestlib-androidnativearm64-1.0.0.module
│   └── mytestlib-androidnativearm64-1.0.0.pom
└── maven-metadata-local.xml

5 directories, 11 files
```

Create the Kotlin Mulitplatform App in AndroidStudio.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-library.html#add-a-dependency-on-the-published-library

Error adding dependencies to androidMain:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVqm1.jpg)

```
Unable to build Kotlin project configuration

org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find mytestlib-1.0.0-samplessources.jar (me.dxy:mytestlib:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
file:/Users/dxy/.m2/repository/me/dxy/mytestlib/1.0.0/mytestlib-1.0.0-samplessources.jar
at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:28)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ExternalResourceResolver.java:510)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:439)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LocalModuleComponentRepository$LocalAccess.resolveArtifact(LocalModuleComponentRepository.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveArtifact$12(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:171)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:227)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:169)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:78)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSupplier.calculateValue(DefaultArtifactSet.java:290)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSupplier.calculateValue(DefaultArtifactSet.java:261)
at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer$CalculationState.lambda$attachValue$0(CalculatedValueContainer.java:218)
at org.gradle.internal.Try.ofFailable(Try.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer$CalculationState.attachValue(CalculatedValueContainer.java:213)
at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer.finalizeIfNotAlready(CalculatedValueContainer.java:186)
at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer.finalizeIfNotAlready(CalculatedValueContainer.java:177)
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant$DownloadArtifactFile.run(ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant.java:192)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$QueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:238)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:266)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.doRunBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:247)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.lambda$runBatch$0(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:237)
at org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractResourceLockRegistry.whileDisallowingLockChanges(AbstractResourceLockRegistry.java:50)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.whileDisallowingProjectLockChanges(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:221)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.lambda$runBatch$1(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:237)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:223)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:191)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: [Please update your question to include the code instead of screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Comment: I'm very sorry, now I also dontknow how to write code for the Native/AndroidNativeArm64. So far we've only done a few of the above experiments based on guesswork. I would like to know how kmm develops Native/Andoird libraries and calls